# How to specify one class of my code not to generate debugging information in debug mode in Visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, release

Now I'm doing a debug on a piece of code that calls a class that has made sure it's okay, but it's running very slowly in debug mode and much faster in release mode with Visual Studio.

Can I ask this class not to generate debugging information? So in debug mode, this class can also run at a good speed?

Comment: Have you profiled the program and make sure "the class" is slowing down the program?

Answer (score 0):

What is slowing down your code is not the generation of debug information, but the lack of optimizations. Release mode enables optimizations that allow your compiler to change your code in a way that produces the same result but in a much faster way. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if. Debug mode disallows these optimizations in order to make it easier to debug (it's in the name), at the cost of execution speed. Debug mode can't get rid of any useless code or make big changes. Use Debug mode to make sure everything works properly, and Release to run it fast when it does work.

If you post your code here we can see if there are any glaring problems with it, but without code the best I can do is the general explanation.